# How would a slideable list control like this be achieved with React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-swiper

The Yelp app for iOS is designed such that after you enter and send a search query, something like this comes up:

The screen consists of a map control in the background, with a screen on top displaying a list view that you can swipe up/down depending on whether you want to see the list/map (respectively).

How would something like this be accomplished using React Native? For example, would the React Navigation or React Native Swiper libraries help me superimpose a list view on top of the map control?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PanResponder.

Here is a good article which ay help you. Click [here](https://moduscreate.com/blog/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native/).